# Prevent autohide status bar at React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

I am developing app on React Native. Now I have a problem, that status bar on Android is auto hiding and auto showing while using app, and therefore content jumps. Is there a way to disable autohiding status bar on Android?

Comment: What do you mean by auto hide? The status bar is shown on some screens ?

Answer (score 0):

For that , you can create a CustomStatusBar component like below,

```js
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { colors } from '../constants'

const CustomStatusBar = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ height: StatusBar.currentHeight, backgroundColor: colors.green }}>

            <StatusBar
                animated
                translucent
                backgroundColor={colors.green}  //use your desired color
                barStyle="light-content"
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default CustomStatusBar

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

})
```

And import this in your App.js file like below,

```js
import CustomStatusBar from "./src/components/CustomStatusBar";

const App = () => {

  return (
      //your remaining codes
  
        <CustomStatusBar />
        
        );
      }
        
        
export default App;
```

By doing this you can set default background color and default height for your StatusBar.Thus , Statusbar will be in default position without autohide